# searching a pattern in text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to replace some words which follow some pattern for example- (:smile:) or (:riya:) or may be (:money:) with space i.e., whenever I found '(:' and ':)', it get replaced by space.

For example:

```
This is a demo text (:ritu:) to demonstrate (:money:) what is the problem.
```

Result:

```
This is a demo text to demonstrate what is the problem.
```

How to achieve this with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.replace`

```js
var str = 'This is a demo text (:ritu:) to demonstrate (:money:) what is the problem.'
alert(str.replace(/\s?\(:.*?:\)/g, ''))
```